# Python Flask jinja - render Dynamically changing html file

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

So right now I have a python script that is part of this web-app.  When the user hits submit on the page, it runs a script in the background and writes to a file called 'diff.html'.  This file is e-mailed to the user in full html.  I would like to render this exact file on the webpage as well.  This works, but it only holds the file that was there when its first rendered.  I would like this to dynamically change every time the web-app is ran.

Or is there a better way to display the HTML file that I have all-ready generated?

```
return render_template('diff.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works perfectly!

```
return send_from_directory('/var/www/templates/','diff.html')
```